# In Swift is there anyway to know which object was swiped?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to pass the sender `redBox` to the function `leftSwipeFunc`. I don't know how to pass a parameter that's not `UISwipeGestureREcognizer`. Please help me if you know the answer.

```
let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("leftSwipeFunc:")) 
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
redBox.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft) 

func leftSwipeFunc(gesture:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Gesture recognizers have a property called `view` that is the `UIView` that they are attached to.  So, you can use that inside of `leftSwipeFunc` to get the view:

```
func leftSwipeFunc(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let swipedView = gesture.view

    // Assuming redBox is a property of your view controller
    if swipedView == redBox {
        println("the redBox was swiped")
    } else {
        println("some other view was swiped")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the location of the swipe in your view using `locationInView`.

In your `leftSwipeFunc`, find the `CGPoint` of the touch and check if it is in the required view.

```
let location = gesture.locationInView(self.view)

if CGRectContainsPoint(redBox, location) {
    // redBox was swiped, do something
}
```